# CCAvenue Installed but not displayed in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, ccavenue

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2. I have installed CCAvenue Package from Magento Connect. Installed Correctly, I also configured with merchant id and key, my base currency is also India Ruppe but still CCAvenue option is not displayed on my Store. Does any body has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install CCAvenue Plugin from the CCavenue Site. After Logging in to Your CCAvenue Account. Click on 3rd Party Integration and download the plugin from there and follow the instructions. Worked for Me

Answer (score -1):

Pls re-index your index-mgmt and cache by logging into admin panel and delete all your cache in var/cache or delete all contents inside var directory of root and re-login.. Hope this may fix your problem!!